# Two GPUs and two monitors on a Debian system, one for text, another for Xorg

Tags: linux, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, xorg, tty

I have a server with an onboard Aspeed VGA card and an Nvidia T400 HDMI card, and two monitors connected physically to those cards. I don't want to install very much software on this machine which is Proxmox and most of the work is done in LXCs and VMs, but I want to run a Firefox kiosk on one of the screens, having another for occasional admin work.

The Nvidia card has to remain accessible to the containers. I've managed to pass it through to a container like described [here](https://theorangeone.net/posts/lxc-nvidia-gpu-passthrough/) but failed to do the same with the mouse, microphone, the keyboard and the screen's multitouch USB input, so I decided it is easier to run this kiosk from the host.

I have successfully installed Xorg (*without any windows manager!*) on host and managed run Firefox with xinit on the HDMI interface while still having the text-based ttys via the VGA. I've pointed Xorg to Nvidia and all of the system's "tty"s are still on the Aspeed VGA, which is my machine main GPU, and it quite looks liek what I want, but the problem is that when I switch "screens" with Ctrl-Alt-Fn from the current "tty" that ran xinit, the graphical screen switches off until I Ctrl-Alt-F1 back to it.

I would like the Xorg to continue working while having access to the textual console.

It's the latest Proxmox which is Debian 12. However I believe there is a really simple distribution-independent tweak, for example, to tell the system that, say, tty3 is connected to another GPU than all the other ones. Is there any?